# DataFrame groupby to display two value counts

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to display two `groupby` results side by side in adjacent columns.

A segment of my data set looks like this:

```
Col1   Col2
T      1010
A      1010
A      1010
A      1010
T      1011
A      1011
T      1011
T      1012
A      1012
A      1012
A      1012
A      1012
T      1012
A      1012
```

I can get the `groupby` to display how many Col1 match with Col2 individually for either T or A using the following code ...

```py
grouped_df_t = df[df['Col1'] == 'T'].Col2.value_counts().to_frame(name = 'Ts').reset_index()
```

This only displays the total of the Col2 values that match with T. I need another column alongside that shows the matches with A.

Tried everything I can think of without success.

Comment: `value_counts()` also works for multiple columns: `df.value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['Col1'], df['Col2'])
Out[553]: 
Col2  1010  1011  1012
Col1                  
A        3     1     5
T        1     2     2
```